# coubtable infinite disjointed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does there exist an infinte set of sets $A$ thats holds the following property:

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist exactly n pairwise disjointed sets in $A$, but there are no infinite pairwise disjointed sets in $A$?

Comment: What has your question to do with *any* of the tags that you chose?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. the `prime numbers` tag was indeed a mistake.

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:number-theory] or [tag:infinite-groups]?

Comment: I've posted an answer to the question which might  explain why this tags are relevant to the question.

Comment: I'll never understand why certain questions are closed and others aren't. The only specific complaint lodged was about the tags, but they were edited by @amWhy. There's only one question asked; it's clear and formatted well.  The OP didn't show an attempt in the post, but did post an answer, not that there aren't tens of thousands of unclosed questions on this site with no attempt shown. Same for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have constructed a set $A$ of sets such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are $n$ sets in $A$ that are pairwise disjoint.

However, you have not shown that there is not an infinite subset of $A$ which is also pairwise disjoint. Showing that a particular sets of $n$ sets is a partition of the union of $A$, and hence that there are no sets that are disjoint from ***those*** is not the same thing.  In my comment, I show that your set $A$ does have an infinite subset of sets that are each pairwise disjoint.

However, your construction is close.

For prime $p$, and $0 \le i < p$, let $a_{p,i} = \{n \in \mathbb{N}| n \equiv i \,(\textrm{mod } p) \}$

Take $A = \{a_{p,i}|p \text{ is prime }, 0\le i < p\}$

It's clear that for $i\ne j$, $a_{p,i} \cap a_{p,j} = \emptyset$.

Since there is no largest prime, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, choose a prime $p>n$ and let the pairwise disjoint sets be: $a_{p,0}, \ldots, a_{p,n-1}$.

To show that there is no infinite set of pairwise disjoint sets, we can show that for any distinct primes $p_1 \ne p_2$, and any $0 \le i < p_1$, and $0 \le j < p_2$, $a_{p_1,i} \cap a_{p_2,j} \ne \emptyset$.

To show that, we need to show that $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$m \equiv i \,(\textrm{mod } p_1)$$
$$m \equiv j \,(\textrm{mod } p_2)$$
If $i=j$, we can take $m = p_1 p_2 +i$.
Otherwise, without loss of generality, take $i<j$.
We know that there exists $n$ such that $np_1\equiv 1 \,(\textrm{mod } p_2)$, so take $m = i + (j-i)np_1$.

Since, for each prime, there are only finitely many sets $a_{p,i}$, any infinite subset of $A$ would have to have $a_{p_1,i}$ and $a_{p_2,j}$ for distinct primes $p_1$ and $p_2$, and hence not be pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT (following Joe answer):**

Ok, so I think I've found a solution.

Let $p_1, p_2$... be all prime numbers, and let $A := \{ a_{p_i,j} \;|\; n\in a_{p_i,j} \iff n \equiv j \mod p_i ,\; 1\leq i,\;  0\leq j< i\}$,

for example:

Let $m=3$, and thats means $p_i = 5 = the \: 3^{rd} prime$.
there exist exactly 3 pairwise disjointed  sets:

$ 
a_{5,0} := \{ n \;|\; n \equiv 0 \mod 5 \}  \\
a_{5,1} := \{ n \;|\; n \equiv 1 \mod 5 \} \\
a_{5,2} := \{ n \;|\; n \equiv 2 \mod 5 \} 
$

and it's easy to prove that every $a_{{p_i}, j}$ where $i \neq 3$ have nonempty intersection with each of this 3 sets.

Comment: What about $\{a_{2,0},a_{4,1},a_{8,3},\ldots,a_{2^n,(2^{n-1}-1)},\ldots\}$

Comment: Thanks Joe! can you check my updated answer? I've read your answer above and changed the index i to be $p_i$

Comment: You want $j<p_i$, not $j<i$. But the bigger problem is that you cannot just show that every set has nonempty intersection with some specific sets. You need to say that (1) any infinite collection of sets in $A$ must necessarily contain $a_{p_i, n}$ and $a_{p_j, m}$ with $p_i \ne p_j$, and (2) those have nonempty intersection.